# Creating custom link that redirects to a another link

Tags: redirect

I'm very new to wordpress (but not on development) and I'm using the wordpress.org GUI. I would like to create a link like this one:
[www.mywordpressSite.com/myCustomPdf](http://www.mywordpressSite.com/myCustomPdf)
(see that this should be a link to a custom pdf that I have on googledrive, **its size is 73mb so it cannot be uploaded to wordpress site**).
Then [www.mywordpressSite.com/myCustomPdf](http://www.mywordpressSite.com/myCustomPdf) should redirect me to a link to some file I uploaded on google drive (For example: drive.google.com/myCustomPDF_Link) .

To make this more clear, when someone goes to [www.mywordpressSite.com/myCustomPdf](http://www.mywordpressSite.com/myCustomPdf), he should be automatically redirected to a file that I uploaded on googleDrive (on drive.google.com/myCustomPDF_Link ) .

Is there any way to do this? Any hint?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First, create a page with the intended URL slug and note down the ID of it. Then in your `functions.php`

```php
function wpse410694_custom_redirect() { 
    //Let us assume the ID of the page is 123
    if ( is_page(123) ) {
        wp_redirect( 'drive.google.com/myCustomPDF_Link' );
        exit;
    }
    
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse410694_custom_redirect');
```

The maximum upload size is normally set from server. You can increase it by tweaking the server settings.